# Closed Subgroups of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

If $F$ is a nonempty closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x-y\in F$ for $x,y\in F$, then show that $F=\mathbb{R}$ or $F=\alpha\mathbb{Z}$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hint: Maybe (i) $F=\{0\}$; (ii) Maybe $F$ has a smallest positive element. (iii) Maybe it doesn't. Case (ii) will give us $\alpha \mathbb{Z}$. Case (iii) is where we need to use the fact that $F$ is closed.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Show that if $F$ is not discrete, then $F$ is dense. Do this by assuming $F$ has a limit point $x_0$ (which is necessarily in $F$), and then for every $\varepsilon>0$ find some $x_\varepsilon\in F$ such that $|x_0-x_\varepsilon|<\varepsilon$. Consider translations to show that every neighborhood of radius $\varepsilon$ has an element of $F$ in it.

Thus, if $F$ isn't $\mathbb{R}$, it must be discrete. Then, use the standard technique of showing that $\inf \{x\in F:x>0\}$ generates $F$.

Comment: First part is fine, but how to show that $\alpha$ generates $F$ in second case?

Comment: @Anupam: Let $\alpha$ be the infimum. By discreteness, we have $\alpha \in F$. Let $\beta \in F \setminus \{0\}$ be arbitrary. By replacing $\beta$ with its inverse, assume that $\beta > 0$. Let $n$ be the largest positive integer such that $n\alpha \leqslant \beta$. (Note that $\alpha \leqslant \beta$, by construction.) Then, $\beta - n\alpha$ is a nonnegative element of $F$ which is strictly less than $\alpha$. Thus, $\beta = n\alpha$ as desired.